# Expand directory list and copy

Tags: powershell, xcopy

I need to copy the following subset of folders from `$sourceDir` to `$targetDir`:

```
abc0001
abc0643
abc0456
...
```

The number of folders is unknown, but they all match a pattern `abc0*`.

Is there an elegant solution to expand `abc0*` to the actual list of folders and then copy them? I tried this:

```
dir "$sourceDir\abc0*" -Recurse | copy -Destination $targetDir -WhatIf
```

But it does not preserve the path, so all files end up in the root of `$targetDir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
dir $sourceDir abc0* | where {$_.psiscontainer} | copy -dest $targetDir -recurse
```

Comment: why not adding the `-recurse` to `get-childitem` also?

Comment: I guess you could do that too but it will be quicker, recursing with copy will drill down on incoming folders only while with gci it will recurse on all child items.